# Use value of variable for property lookup

Tags: swift, properties

I am trying to build a table of current locale properties in code, and have encountered issues with trying to pass the value of a variable to a function:

```
let currentLocale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")

let calendar1 = currentLocale.calendar      // "gregorian (fixed)"

let propertyName = "calendar"
let calendar2 = currentLocale.propertyName // Error: Value of type 'Locale' has no member 'porpertyName'
```

In the last line of code above, the instance of Locale thinks I am passing it "propertyName" rather than the contents of the variable "calendar".

Is there any way to pass the value of propertyName ("calendar") to the instance of Locale? I know that in other languages, you can prepend the variable name like '$propertyName', and that tells it to read the value of the variable.

I want to keep this pure Swift if possible.

Comment: You're not calling a function with arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for some form of *[key-value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)*.

It's a little tricky, in that this is a purely Objective-C feature of Cocoa, so it doesn't work with the Swift overlay class Locale; you will have to cast `currentLocale` to Objective-C NSLocale. Moreover, NSLocale exposes its attributes through special NSLocale.Key types. After a great deal of casting, I find that this works:

```
let calendar2 = 
    (currentLocale as NSLocale).object(forKey:NSLocale.Key(rawValue:propertyName))
```

`calendar2` is typed as Any but you can cast it down to a String.

Comment: `object(forKey:)`, the method on `NSLocale`, needs a valid NSLocale component key, which "calendar" is not. Do you mean `valueForKey(_:)`?

Comment: Yes @Matt, when I plug that line into the code, I get  the error: Value of type 'Locale' has no member 'object'.

Comment: Yeah, I got it working, but it wasn't easy! A much more interesting challenge than I expected.

Comment: @Matt, that works, but I must admit that it wasn't what I expected. Many thanks for giving me a working answer!

Comment: Because Swift can infer the `NSLocale.Key` type for the `forKey:` parameter, you could also write it as `.object(forKey:.init(rawValue:propertyName))` – although this may be sacrificing clarity for brevity.